# <Power Automate> Include name of person who uploaded file to SharePoint in e-mail

Tags: power-automate

I am using [this Power Automate Flow](https://emea.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/352516eb50dd4f5685be03d9fb97cdc0/send-an-email-when-a-file-is-created-in-a-folder-of-onedrive-for-business/).

I need the name of the person who uploaded the file, but don't see a way to include this through dynamic content. My plan is to add it to the body of the e-mail sent so that the recipient knows who uploaded the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user who has last modified the file by using another action which I have specified in the image below

[Flow action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eB02.png)

Hope this has solved your question

Regards
RT

Comment: Hi RT - that worked perfectly! thank you!